# How do I write this Regex to not match these terms?

Tags: regex

I'm fairly new to regex. I've written this expression to use in File Renamer (JS) so I can arrange the files by the surname (they start with the firstname and cannot be changed), it places an "!" infront of all the files whose surname begin with the letter it is set to (in this instance "A") so they can then be moved to a separate folder. It works perfect except for several terms which give false positives, ie: "and" "with" "Jr" "Sn" "II" "III" "IV". I cannot find a way to make it ignore these terms, is it possible?

```
(^[\w\.\s]+\bA[\w]+(,|\s-|\s&))
!$1
```

[1]: http://regex101.com/r/qU4yJ6/4 [See this Link][1]

It must match the first surname (last word) before any of these terms " - " "&" "," "and" "with" "Jr" "Sn" "II" "III" "IV"

--------------- MATCH -------------------

```
John Albert - Work00 - october.txt
Fred Allen - blah 01 - Whatever.txt
B. B. Archer - blah.txt
John M. Aines - Abcdef - {12345}.txt
A Arthur - abcdef.txt
Alex Abbott & Jane Doe - details.txt
D.C. Atkins, John Smith - Zxy123.txt
B. A. Arnold Jr, - (or Sn,) - def01.txt
Paul Adams III - (or II or IV).txt
Dave Ahern with Jo Short - [00].txt
```

-----------DO NOT MATCH-------------

```
J Anthony Jones - yawn - zzzz.txt
Rand Sony et al - title.txt
AA Smith - lalala.txt
A.A. Bloggs - info00 - November.txt
A A Bilner - testing1234.txt
A. Lebert - Anything - October.txt
A Doe - etc - etc.txt
A & A Dell - Defghi.txt
A and A Bell - asdfghjkl.txt
```

Comment: [Obligatory link about using regex for name matching.](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Sam is right - this stuff is hard to get right. Why do you need to do this anyway? Using the first letter of the surname seems a bit of an arbitrary choice - if you want to divide the files into subdirectories but don't really care what subdirectories you use, then it's not worth the effort of working out which parts are the surnames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this pattern

```
^(?:(?![-&,]|and|with|Jr|Sn|II|III).)*\b(A\w+)\b(?=\s*(?:[-&,]|and|with|Jr|Sn|II|III))
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qU4yJ6/6)

Comment: Thanks for trying. Your expression has the same problem as all my attempts, For Example when using it to look for surnames beginning with 'J' or an 'I' it will match 'Jr' or 'III' instead of the surname (Change the 'A' in the regex to J or I to see what I mean). Seems like it would be a simple thing to get it to ignore those terms but I cant seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: use `J(?!r\b)`, `I(?!I+\b)` and `S(?!n\b)` instead of `A`

Comment: @ alpha bravo, Any idea how I stop this incorrect match: http://regex101.com/r/gA5kD4/1 it is wrongly matching single words beginning with A in front of ampersand? Thanks.

Comment: @ alpha bravo, You're a star! I never thought of adding it to the end. Can this last one be matched without messing up any of the others? http://regex101.com/r/hC1cE9/2  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put an optional alternator selector (x|y|z)? in the middle of that to pick up those terms you list.

This only has enough of your terms to do your examples, but its a start:

```
(^[\w\.\s]+\bA[\w]+(\s(Jr|III|with[^-]*))?(,|\s-\s.|\s&))
```

I tried that on regex101 sample and it worked.

EDIT:

When faced with processing surnames whose first letter matches the alternator selector you can do a negative lookahead to ensure you are not matching the wrong thing. You will need to customize the express per letter beyond just swapping the single match letter in some cases.

In you example data, for J, you would no want to match:

```
B. A. Arnold Jr, - abc - def01.txt
Dave Ahern with Jo Short - [00].txt.
```

but would want to match:

```
J Anthony Jones - yawn - zzzz.txt
```

Using a negative lookahead will let you process Js. [J|Jr Example](http://regex101.com/r/dO2uW2/2)

```
(^[\w\.\s]+\bJ(?!r,)[\w]+(\s(Jr|III|with[^-]*))?(,|\s-\s.|\s&))
```

This may be more complicated then it worth to try to accomplish with a in such one line regex's.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Your expression has the same problem as all my attempts, For Example when using it to look for surnames beginning with 'J' or an 'I' it will match 'Jr' or 'III' instead of the surname (Change the 'A' in the regex to J or I to see what I mean). Seems like it would be a simple thing to get it to ignore those terms but I cant seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: Well, you can avoid that wit a negative lookahead, but you'll need to mod the expression a bit more than just swapping out the letter as you change target letters. I'll edit to show and example.